# Unable to run the react application after updating from Node v14.21.3 to Node v20.9.0

Tags: reactjs

When I updated the node version from v14.21.3 to v20.9.0 and updated the packages for react application, the .md files are getting executed and throwing errors.

Eg:

```
ERROR in ./src/styleguidist/sections/getting-started/project-setup.md (./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/loaders/examples-loader.js!./src/styleguidist/sections/getting-started/project-setup.md) 9:72-147
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'template/dist/style/core/css/colorscheme-oceanside.min.css' in 'C:\react-app\src\styleguidist\sections\getting-started'
 @ ./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/loaders/styleguide-loader.js!./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/index.js 46:31-241
 @ ./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/index.js 38:19-71 58:2-61:4 58:65-61:3
```

Can anyone please suggest what can be done.

Comment: Can you explain the problem? What command did you run? How did you generate your project (e.g. create-react-app?)

Comment: We have an application created 5 years ago. Unfortunately, I don't know how the project is generated. I am trying to update the packages and node versions in order to prevent security vulnerabilities. I ran "npm run docs" to run the application. When I run the application, it is running the project-setup.md file as well which is supposed to be a web page content and throwing errors as mentioned in the post. can you please suggest if there is a work around for this. Thanks!

Comment: Check what command is run when you do `npm run docs`. Is it possible that you accidentally upgraded the react-styleguidist package in addition to react?